# Подскажите где какую скобку я пропускаю. Сниппеты Emmet

Tags: emmet

```
.section>det>ul>li.element{Click }+a{here}+{ to go on page }$*5

<div class="section">
    <details>
      <ul>
        <li class="element">Click </li>
        <a href="">here</a> to go on page  to go on page  to go on page  to go on page  to go on page 
      </ul>
    </details>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.section>det>ul>li.element*5>{Click }+a{here}+{ to go on page $}
```